# Java string comparison is not working when concatenated with number

Tags: java

My question to java folks is, when I am comparing two strings

```
imageName=new String[20];    
....    
imageName[1]="img1";  
imageName[2]="img1";  

if(imageName[1]==imageName[2])  
{  
 ////  codes  
}
```

it works perfectly, but when I am making the string through number concatenation it's not working

```
imageName=new String[20];  
int j=1,k=1;  
imageName[1]="img"+j;  
imageName[2]="img"+k;

 if(imageName[1].toString()==imageName[2].toString())     
        {  
           ////  codes  
        }
```

it's not working though the values of j and k are the same

Thanks in advance for your solution

Comment: Another day, another `==` String comparison

Comment: The long answer involves how Java represents strings internally, but the short answer is to not use == to compare strings.  Use .compareTo.

Comment: @Thomas -- no, use `equals()`.

Comment: `String#equals(String str2)`. Example: `if (imageName[1].equals(imageName[2]))...`

Comment: @Pshemo Actually, he is a little bit more confused than the usual `==` String comparer, because he also stumbled upon a consequence of the flyweight pattern...

Comment: @user1595652  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) question may be helpfull

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) when comparing two Strings:

```
if (imageName[1].equals(imageName[2])
```

Comment: Incidentally, "string".intern() == "string".intern() is valid :)

Comment: @ChrisMoran It's valid because "string".equals("string") is true. From the javadoc, `It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true. `

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't compare strings with `==`, but instead use the `.equals` method: `imageName[1].equals(imageName[2])`.

`==` compares the pointers for equality, so it'll be `true` if both variables represent the exact same instance in memory. In the first case, it's the case because Java pools String literals for performance. But in your second case, you're getting two distinct heap-allocated objects, which, despite their **content** is identical, are two distinct objects nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing whether the two String are exactly the same object.

What you intended was to compare their contents. I suggest you use `.equals` instead.

Answer (score 1):

*Never*, ever, use "==" to compare Strings in Java. Use the `equals()` method. The `==` operator checks to see if two String variables are referring to the same location in memory, while the `equals()` method checks whether two separate String objects contain the same characters. It's this second definition that makes sense here: your String concatenation is creating separate String objects, but we still want to consider them as "equal".

Answer (score 1):

`The correct way to compare strings is using equals() method`

So, Please change your code as below,

```
if (imageName[1].equals(imageName[2])
```

And please consider to do a research in SO before posting, as the questions like this have been answered many times before.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two `String`s you better use `equals()` method

 `if(imageName[1].equals(imageName[2]))

        {

           ////  codes

        }`

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a reference comparison. That is, you're determining if the two objects are, in fact, the same object. If you use `equals()` then that method comparses the contents of the string i.e. do those objects have the same contents (you'll appreciate there is a subtle difference here)

Your first scenario works since the compiler is clever enough to realise that you have the same string twice. i.e. it looks at:

```
imageName[1]="img1";  
imageName[2]="img1";
```

and determines that your array elements can point to the *same* object. In your second scenario, that's no longer true.

```
imageName[1]="img"+j;  
imageName[2]="img"+k;
```

The compiler can't reliably determine that these could be the same string object (quite correctly, too).

So (generally speaking) you should use equals() to compare `Strings`. You can use the reference equality (it's faster since it comparse the references rather than the string contents), but you have to be *absolutely sure* about what you're doing (perhaps you're using `String.intern()` - but there are [disadvantages](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html) there)